# Problem about circle tangents

Tags: geometry

> Circles $c_1$ and $c_2$ with origins $O_1$ and $O_2$ are on plane. $O_1Z$ and $O_1X$are tangents to Circle $c_2$.These tangents intersect $c_1$ in $A$ and $B$.$O_2Y$ and $O_2T$are tangents to Circle $c_1$.These tangents intersect $c_2$ in $C$ and $D$. Prove $AB=CD$

**Figure**
[image]

*Things I have done:* I was able to Prove that quadrilateral $JO_1LO_2$ is Kite (Triangles $O_2J O_1$ and $O_2L O_1$ are congruent by Angle-Side-Angle). So  $JO_1=LO_1$ and $CO_2=DO_2$. $O_1A=O_1B$ because Both of them are radius.So $JA=BL$.Similar to this,$CJ=DL$. So By Side-Angle-Side, $CJA$ and $DLB$ are congruent.So $AC=BD$. So if I Prove that $AC ||DB$,then $CABD$ will be a Parallelogram So $DC=AB$ will be true.This where I stuck.

I would Appreciate if someone could edit title to something better.

Comment: As it turns out, this question is a duplicate; see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/455395/409 . I like [my answer there](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/455415/409) better than the one I gave below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $O_2 Y\perp O_1 Y$ and $O_1 Z\perp O_2 Z$, $O_1 Y Z O_2$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. This gives that $JO_1 Y$ and $JO_2 Z$ are similar triangles, so:
$$\frac{JO_1}{O_1 A}=\frac{JO_1}{O_1 Y}=\frac{JO_2}{O_2 Z}=\frac{JO_2}{O_2 C}\tag{1}$$
but $(1)$ gives that $AC$ is parallel to $O_1 O_2$ due to Thales' theorem. Obviously the same holds for $BD$, and both $CD$ and $AB$ are perpendicular to $O_1 O_2$, hence $ACDB$ is a rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$$\begin{align}
\triangle O_1RP \sim \triangle O_2SP &\qquad\implies\qquad \frac{r}{|O_1P|}=\frac{s}{|O_2P|} \quad=: k\\[6pt]
\triangle O_1PQ \sim \triangle O_1BA &\qquad\implies\qquad \frac{|AB|}{|PQ|}=\frac{r}{|O_1P|} = k \quad\to\quad |AB| = k\;|PQ|\\[6pt]
\triangle O_2PQ \sim \triangle O_2DC &\qquad\implies\qquad \frac{|CD|}{|PQ|}=\frac{s}{|O_2P|} = k \quad\to\quad |CD| = k\;|PQ|
\end{align}$$